# using to layout tableView's with masonry

Tags: ios, uitableview, masonry

My tableView isn't fullscreen or set with static height. It needs to change tableView's cell height after data is returned from server. So how can I layout my tableView with masonry ?

Comment: use self sizing cells https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: I know how to this api,But i tried but it didn't work

Comment: add screenshot of your tableviewcell and constraints applied

Answer (score 0):

You should add a layout about tableView's height. When you get a newest height and then change layout's constant. In your code, you can call `layoutSubviews` in tableview owner after finishing network loading.

Comment: so I still have to calculate the height of every cell,then add them?

Comment: I don't think so. UITableView is subclass of  UIScrollView. I'm not clear the reason why you must change tableview's height. Do you need table's height is just suitable it‘s content? and then table doesn't scroll?

Comment: I want table's height suit its content. for example, I have three cell ,cell's height is 40. then, I want table is automatic suit its height

Comment: If like this, you maybe realize only with calculate all cell's height and make the table's height is the add result. If the cell's height is constant, table's height = cells' count * cell's height. If not, follow your mind. Because table itself can't make a decision by variable content , `sizeToFit` is invalid.(`UIButton`、`UIImageView` and `UILabel` are valid like this with fixed content in some degrees.)